What are GIFVs?
I heard about GIFVs from Imgur, but what exactly are they? How do I make some? Are GIFV files lossless?
I tried looking onto it from the site but I got an error. http://blog.imgur.com/2014/10/09/introducing-gifv/

.gifv is a file format that was made by Imgur. It is less of a .gif and more of a video file. Specifically, it compiles in the end to either .mp4 or .webm formats (at the time of writing this - they might use other formats later). This enables better compression and extra features like controls and sound.
So why call it a .gifv? Two reasons that I can think of:

It gives the appearance of a GIF-like thing. It encourages short videos and sharing in ways that GIFs are usually shared.
Using a single link, they can serve different file formats. This allows them to send a compatible video file type based on the user's device.

For more, see an archived version of the link that you shared.

Are GIFV files lossless?

No. Modern web video file formats are all lossy.

How do I make some?

You can use some online services and software to create ".gifv" files. But you probalby just want to make .mp4 + .webm files (or another modern format like .avif) instead. For more info, see this post or many others about generating video files.

How do you know that GIFV files are lossless?

Oops, sorry, I meant to say "No" there like I did in the second sentence. Again, GIFV is not really a true file format. It is just another web video format underneath, which are all lossy

That is only a gimmick from Imgur. They are mp4 videos.
And any video we use in modern days are lossy formats, the only exceptions are the RAW ones used in production workflows, which are very bulky.

So GIFV files are not lossless?

No. It is not. Any video file is lossy.
